# Android toolbar custom layout element click event

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have created a custom toolbar for my project . Toolbar is working fine and showing . Here is the code for toolbar

**toolbar.xml**

```
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:weightSum="8">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageToolbal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/alert_on"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textToolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

layout for main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my `onCreate` method of the code , I have set up toolbar like this

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

It is showing as expected , but I can't trigger a click event for the layout in toolbar . Like I want to show a `Toast` if click on the `textView` in the toolbar with the id `textToolbar` , or I want to hide and show it conditionally . How can I do it ?

Comment: Toolbar is just a view. You can use toolbar.findViewById(x); to get any child view like textview in your case. Then you can do what ever you want.

Comment: Do you set any `onClickListener`?

Comment: find your textview and set an onClickListener on it. Toolbar is just a normal view like any other view

Comment: @mSapps see below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//change in "res/styles.xml"

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

// in activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar mToolbar;
TextView txtToolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    //textView inside toolbar
    txtToolbar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    txtToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Toolbar Item","TxtClicked");
        }
    });
}
```

}

//toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToolBar TextView"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar manipulation like this.

```
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // Title and subtitle
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.about_toolbar_title);
        toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.themeToolbarColor));
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // finish();
            }
        });
        toolbar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch your toolbar textview as below:

```
  TextView textToolbar= (TextView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.textToolbar);

  textToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         // YOUR TOAST HERE
        }
    });
```

And hide and show as below:

```
    if(YOUR_CONDITION){
       textToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
       textToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign an `xml` `onClick` event for the `textView` that you want to click and then implement that in `Activity`.

The `xml` would be like,

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textToolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"
            android:onclick="test"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>
```

and the method for implementing the onclick event would be ,

```
public void test(View V){
   //onclick event statement
}
```